# Read JWT token content in REST Service

Tags: spring, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Hi I am using Spring Security Oauth2 with JWTTokenStore. I want to read the token content from REST Service once the user sends it back with resource request.
eg:
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer " http://localhost:8080/api/UserDetails

read token in UserDetails service.

thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/nielsutrecht/jwt-angular-spring  Check this project it is simple and effective and has that " Authorization: Bearer " as you call it.

Answer (score 0):

if your request header have the jwt token. do the following

```
String jwtToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey")
                                .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken).getBody();
claims.getSubject();
claims.getExpiration();
```

where secretkey is the key used while you creating jwt token.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do that:

```
((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .getAuthentication().getDetails())
        .getTokenValue();
```

The advantage of this first option is mocking in integration tests.

Or:

```
@AutoWired
private OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext ;

public void getToken() {
    String token = oAuth2ClientContext.getAccessToken().getValue();
}
```

I really don't know how to mock the OAuth2ClientContext in integration test.

Or (if the token are passed using the name "Authorization"):

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
    .currentRequestAttributes())
        .getRequest().getHeader("Authorization");
```